# Intellij Idea Code Indentetion Confuses at Comments

Tags: intellij-idea, auto-indent

When I create a Java file a Javadoc command author is added to file by me. Intellij IDEA also adds date and time which are not yet implemented to Javadoc yet as a comment. When I do auto code indentation it becomes like that:

```
/**
 * @author kamaci
 *         Date: 11.01.2013
 *         Time: 00:47
 */
```

instead of:

```
/**
 * @author kamaci
 * Date: 11.01.2013
 * Time: 00:47
 */
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to uncheck "align parameter descriptions" in Settings->Code Style->Java->JavaDoc(tab)

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck "Enable leading asterisks". 
Reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/code-style-java.html?origin=old_help